# Javadoc errors due to illegal package name

Tags: eclipse, ant, package, javadoc

So my code works fine and all it looks good. But, when generating my Javadoc i get these errors:

```
    javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "eclipse-workspacelab1.0doc - 
    sourcepath C:UsersOwner"
    javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "\eclipse-workspace\lab1.0\src"
    javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "C:\Users\Owner"
    javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "eclipse- 
    workspacelab1.0srcDriver.java C:UsersOwner"
    javadoc: error - File not found: "\eclipse-workspace\lab1.0\src\Lab.java"
```

Can anybody give me any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: what do you use to generate the javadoc?

Comment: Sorry if this the exact answer your looking for, but I starting to use Eclipse @gumol

Comment: There are several ways to create Javadoc in Eclipse (Ant, Maven, Gradle, _File > Export..._). Which one did you use? By the way, in `sourcepath C:UsersOwner` some '\' (or '/') are missing.

Comment: @howlger I think it's an ant script base on what I can find in my Eclipse version

Comment: What steps did you take to create Javadoc (which menu item, buttons, etc. did you clicked)? If it is an Ant script, please add it to your question.

Comment: @howlger I went to project > Generate Javadoc. selcect lab1.0. choose private and use standard doc at C:\Users\Owner'\eclipse-workspace\lab1.0\doc

Comment: Can you show a source file?

Comment: Does the project _lab1.0_ have Java Build Path or compile errors? From which JDK is the `javadoc` command called (in the dialog the full path of the _Javadoc command_ is shown; please tell us what you get if you call this command on the command line with the argument `-J-version`)?

Comment: @howlger I do some research to check what I did wrong, but I think I might have found something out. So my computer username is "Owner' " but the error only shows "Owner " without the apostrophe. May that be reason?

Comment: Yes, maybe (you could try a workspace or a project that is not located in the user directory). I guess it has something to do with the paths that Eclipse passes as parameters to the Javadoc tool. Can you please add the output of `<javadoc command> -J-version` and the absolute path of the `lab1.0` project directory to your question?